# Search Pandas Column for Substring in other Column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have an example .csv, imported as df.csv, as follows:

```
    Ethnicity, Description
  0 French, Irish Dance Company
  1 Italian, Moroccan/Algerian
  2 Danish, Company in Netherlands
  3 Dutch, French
  4 English, EnglishFrench
  5 Irish, Irish-American
```

I'd like to check the pandas `test1['Description']` for strings in  `test1['Ethnicity']`. This should return rows 0, 3, 4, and 5 as the description strings contain strings in the ethnicity column.

So far I've tried:

```
df[df['Ethnicity'].str.contains('French')]['Description']
```

This returns any specific string, but I'd like to iterate through without searching for each specific ethnicity value. I've also tried converting the columns to lists and iterating through but can't seem to find a way to return the row, as it is no long a DataFrame().

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with values in column `Ethnicity` converted [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) and then `join` by `|` what is in [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `or`:

```
print ('|'.join(df.Ethnicity.tolist()))
French|Italian|Danish|Dutch|English|Irish

mask = df.Description.str.contains('|'.join(df.Ethnicity.tolist()))
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: Description, dtype: bool

#boolean-indexing
print (df[mask])
  Ethnicity          Description
0    French  Irish Dance Company
3     Dutch               French
4   English        EnglishFrench
5     Irish       Irish-American
```

It looks like you can omit `tolist()`:

```
print (df[df.Description.str.contains('|'.join(df.Ethnicity))])
  Ethnicity          Description
0    French  Irish Dance Company
3     Dutch               French
4   English        EnglishFrench
5     Irish       Irish-American
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it! This works when implemented. I don't have much experience with Regular Expression Operations (regex), I'll be sure read up.

Answer (score 1):

the ever popular double apply:

```
df[df.Description.apply(lambda x: df.Ethnicity.apply(lambda y: y in x)).any(1)]

  Ethnicity          Description
0    French  Irish Dance Company
3     Dutch               French
4   English        EnglishFrench
5     Irish       Irish-American
```

---

#### Timing

jezrael's answer is far superior

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works upon implementation.