# how to find keyword find between two dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

hi I have two dataframes,

```
DF1

Name    |  Class

pechi   |  Mr pechi lives in India
Kumar   |  Mr kumar lives in US


DF2,

Name   |

Kumar
```

If the string present in DF2, matches with anyone of the string in DF1["Class"]

then the entire row from DF1 should get appended in my DF3

```
My desired DF3 Should be,

 DF3,

 Name    |  Class

Kumar    |  Mr kumar lives in US
```

some help me in solving this.

I tried this method

```
   if df1[['Class']].str.contains(item1):
   but I am getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Pandas Column for Substring in other Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128353/search-pandas-column-for-substring-in-other-column)

Answer (score 1):

Use `isin` and boolean indexing:

```
DF3 = DF1[DF1.Name.isin(DF2.Name)]
```

Output:

```
    Name                   Class
1  Kumar    Mr kumar lives in US
```

Comment: how do I get this index of this row in DF1, so that I can append it to DF3

Comment: DF3 = DF1[DF1.Name.isin(DF2.Name)]   That will get the indexes and values and put it into DF3.

Comment: I am getting "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided"

Comment: I need DF1.Name.contains(DF2.Name) not isin